# Rounding the largest integer in Haskell

Tags: haskell, rounding

I have this function that tries to count the numbers of a number entered.

```
round_larg :: Float -> Int
round_larg a = (round(round(a)+0.5))
```

The funtion have to round to the largest of a number gives the number of digits that number has.

Then it occurred to me to do rounding rounding but I do not know how to do this in haskell.

Comment: What about [floor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:floor) or [`ceiling`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:ceiling)

Comment: What is "rounding rounding"?

Comment: Notice Haskell's `round` function is round-to-even (aka Banker's Rounding).

Comment: What does "count the numbers of a number" mean? What does any of this have to do with the number of digits?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to use ceiling function.
Thus:

```
round_larg :: Float -> Int
round_larg a = ceiling (a)
```

Comment: `ceiling` is not a keyword, just a function.